# Why are these two complex exponentials equal?

Tags: complex-numbers

Why is $$e^{i(\theta+\pi)} = -e^{i\theta}$$
I saw this but I'm not sure why it works. If someone could show me the steps I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show : $$e^{i(\theta+\pi)}=-e^{i\theta}$$

Now $$e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta \cdots  (1)$$

so    $$e^{i(\theta+\pi)}=\cos (\theta+\pi) + i \sin (\theta+\pi) \cdots  (2)$$

Also , recall that $$\cos (\pi+\theta) = -\cos \theta $$
and $$\sin (\pi+\theta) = -\sin \theta $$

From the above results $(2)$ modifies to $$e^{i (\theta+\pi)} = -(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$$

Therefore from $(1)$ $$e^{i(\theta+\pi)}=-e^{i\theta}$$

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: @StrugglingMathStudent Happy to help ! Let me know if any more doubts persist. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** this is wrong as it is, it should read
$$e^{i(\theta+\pi)}=-e^{i\theta}$$
(theta and pi in the same brackets - edited).

**Hint2:** what functional equation does the exponential map satisfy? $e^{a+b}=\ldots$

Comment: Is it because they are both circles of radius one?

Therefore, is e^i(θ+π)=−e^iθ also = e^iθ ?

Comment: The two numbers both lie on the same circle of radius $1$, yes. But this fact alone is not enough.

Comment: Ohh is it because the first one is the number one rotated by pi, and the second one is the number -1 not rotated, so they both end up at -1?

Comment: Yes :) except there is $e^{i\theta}$ on the way, but you can cancel it from each side and end up with what you said.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Can you explain what you mean by "on the way"?

Sorry - this is my first time working with complex numbers and I'm really bad at it.

Comment: On the one hand you have $e^{i\theta}$ rotated by $\pi$, and on the other hand you have $-e^{i\theta}$. Eventually they are the same for exactly the reason you said: rotating a complex number by $\pi$ is the same as taking its negative.

Comment: I was also suggesting that you prove it by $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$ together with $e^{i\pi}=-1$ (same argument, but with algebraic notations).

Comment: @StrugglingMathStudent I have posted the answer below using trigonometric identities.